Absolute value of a Bochner measurable function is Bochner measurable?
Let $u:[a,b]\to H^1(\Omega)$ be a Bochner measurable function. We define:
$$|u|:[a,b]\to H^1(\Omega),\ |u|(t)=|u(t,\cdot)|\in H^1(\Omega)$$
Here we have used the well-known fact that the modulus of a Sobolev function is also a Sobolev function. To be more precise, see Theorem 2.2 and Remark 2.3 from here https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf
How can we prove that $|u|:[a,b]\to H^1(\Omega)$ is Bochner measurable?
I tried to take a sequence $s_n:[a,b]\to H^1(\Omega)$ of simple functions with $s_n(t)\to u(t)$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ for a.a. $t\in (a,b)$.
I showed that $|s_n(t)|\to |u(t)|$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ since $||s_n(t)|-|u(t)||\leq |s_n(t)-u(t)|$ but I'm having big problems with the gradients. I mean, I don't think it is true that:
$$|\nabla|s_n(t)|-\nabla|u(t)||\leq |\nabla s_n(t)-\nabla u(t)|$$
Or maybe it is...I don't know.

Please give your own thoughts and some context.

I have edited my post.

Can you use $\nabla |s_n| = \sgn(s_n)\nabla s_n$ in some way?

You can use dominated convergence. Assume $v_n \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$. After extracting a subsequence, we have $v_n(x) \to u(x)$ and $\nabla v_n(x) \to \nabla u(x)$ for almost all $x$. In addition, there is a dominating function $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ such that $|v_n(x)| + |\nabla v_n(x)| \le g(x)$ for a.a. $x$.
[See Brezis "Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces, PDEs" or your favourite proof that $L^p$ is complete.]
If $x$ is such that $u(x) \ne 0$, then $v_n(x) \ne 0$ for large $n$, and
$\nabla |v_n|(x)= \nabla v_n(x) \to \nabla u(x) = \nabla |u|(x)$. Similarly, we get $\nabla |v_n|(x) \to \nabla |u|(x)$ if $u(x)<0$.
We know that for almost all $x$
$$
\nabla\max(u,0)(x) = \begin{cases} sign(u(x)) \nabla u(x) & \text{ if } u(x)>0,\\
0 & \text{ if } u(x)\le0.
\end{cases}
$$
This implies that
$$
\nabla u(x) = 0 \text{ a.e. on } \{x: \ u(x) =0\}.
$$
Now, if $u(x) = 0$ then $\nabla v_n(x) \to 0 = \nabla u(x)$, which implies $\nabla |v_n|(x) \to 0$ by the expression for $\nabla |v_n|(x)$. Now we can use dominated convergence to conclude.

I think you are not right...The argument that there is such function $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ is not correct. See here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171574/convergence-in-the-absence-of-dct-uniform-integrability-and-limsup-ex-n

you missed the phrase ``after extracting a subsequence''
